# Firefox HTML5 Video Audio crackles

Tags: firefox, audio, html5-video, html5-audio, codec

when embedding a bigger video in firefox i got audio bugs. **It crackles like an old movie.**
No problems in Chrome.

The video was converted with VLC to **MP4/MOV** with **H-264 video** and **MPEG audio** codecs.
Because of its a very high quality video, the file size and Bitrates are very high. Is it possible, that firefox has a problem with that?

I know, usually you should never offering a video with that size on a web template, but its local hosted for an kiosk-mode project.

**Example File:**

```
FILE
Name:   Holliday_Hawaii_2019.mp4
Type:   MP4 File
Size:   5.39 GB (5.78.399.926 Bytes)

VIDEO
Resolution:     1920 x 1080 px
Data rate:      8082 kBit/s
Total bitrate:  8721 kBit/s
Frame rate:     23.98 Pictures/Second

AUDIO
Bit rate:       638 kBit/s
Channels:       2
Audio sample:   44.100 kHz
```

Comment: I am experiencing a very similiar problem. No crackle in chrome, but Firefox crackles every 1 minute or so.